# Starting activity doesn't call onDestory of current activity

Tags: android

I have the following code in onOptionsItemSelected. The problem I am having is the onDestroy never gets called. Is this normal? Is there a standard procedure to follow?

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(StoreWebActivity.this, StoreUrlActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: yes this is standard, when you start another program on windows from another program the original doesn't close does it? same thing here.

Comment: It goes to onPause first and then if you never go back (resume), it will eventually get killed

Comment: this should clarify things http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [finish](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) the current `Activity` then `onDestroy()` will be called.

Suppose, you called the `finish()` method to finish current activity as below then `onDestroy()` will be called.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(StoreWebActivity.this, StoreUrlActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

You can get more information about [onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) method from Developer site. If you study the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) then you will understand why `onDestroy()` not always called.

Comment: Indeed it should. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29